# How to load page when using colorbox next button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

I am using colorbox (http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) to call ajax html files.

These html files load js arrays into tables like the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/2waZ2/21/

This all works fine, but when the colorbox next button is pressed the JS table data does not load up.

I think it may be because document.onload has already happened.  Even though Im trying to call the JS in the ajax html files I can only seem to get the table data on the 1st page.  After clicking next the table data doesnt show.

I was thinking of trying to change the behavior of the next button in order to get the table data showing.  Any ideas?

This is the next button code I could find in jquery.colorbox.js:

```
$next.click(function () {
        publicMethod.next();
    });
```

And

```
$groupControls = $next.add($prev).add($current).add($slideshow);
```

And

```
    $(document).bind('keydown.' + prefix, function (e) {
        var key = e.keyCode;
        if (open && settings.escKey && key === 27) {
            e.preventDefault();
            publicMethod.close();
        }
        if (open && settings.arrowKey && $related[1]) {
            if (key === 37) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $prev.click();
            } else if (key === 39) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $next.click();
            }
        }
    });
```

and

```
$next[(settings.loop || index < total - 1) ? "show" : "hide"]().html(settings.next);
```

Comment: If the colorbox is using `.load()` keep in mind it won't work locally in Chrome due to Chrome's file access permissions.

Comment: Im using firefox and a server

Answer (score 0):

"I think it may be because document.onload has already happened. Even though Im trying to call the JS in the ajax html files I can only seem to get the table data on the 1st page."

It seems like you might be mixing things up.  In this case, **Document.onload** pertains only to the parent page (the one to the call to colorbox in it.)  Think of Ajax as an alternative way to load content that doesn't trigger **Document.onload**.

I'm not confident that messing with the Next button is your answer.  If you want different HTML to display on the click of next, why not prepare it as such.

Investigate ColorBox's onLoad callback. In other words relocate your custom JS from the displayed HTML file to inside the parent with the job of emitting the html that ColorBox displays.

Comment: Thanks for that. Im not sure I understand it all but Ill see how much I can understand.  What Ive got up to since is - it seems the code is working.  If I change the ids of the divs for the text to be appended to - it works.  If they are the same from file a, click next to file b - (I froze it with an alert) - It looks like it appends for a second time, and them removes both lines, leaving the page blank!!